# How to place a button next to a text?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

Hey guys I need to place these two buttons next to a name. How can I do that? They always appear below the word.

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services">
        <h2>{{service.name}}</h2>
        <button ion-fab mini color="danger"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab mini color="secondary"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was this one:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services | orderBy: 'name'">
    <ion-label>{{service.name}}</ion-label>
    <button (click)="onActive(service.detalhe.id)" *ngIf="service.isActive" ion-button outline item-right>Desativar</button>
    <button (click)="onActive(service.detalhe.id)" *ngIf="!service.isActive" ion-button outline item-right>Ativar</button>
    <button (click)="openUpdatePage(service)" ion-fab mini color="secondary" item-right><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    <button (click)="deleteService(service)" ion-fab mini color="danger" item-right><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-item>
```

Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 7):

Try using this in CSS.

```css
        h2 {
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
         <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services">
                <h2>{{service.name}}</h2>
                <button ion-fab mini color="danger"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>  </button>
                <button ion-fab mini color="secondary"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need:

```
<h2 style="display: inline;">{{service.name}}</h2>
```

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services">
        <h2 style="display:inline;">{{service.name}}</h2>
        <button ion-fab mini color="danger"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab mini color="secondary"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the value parse into your `service.name` contains `'\n'`?

Comment: No, there is just a name like 'painting', but I will try out with another value, another variable

Answer (score 2):

`h2` is a block tag, which means it always tries to take up its own line. You can circumvent this by overriding its display style.

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services">
        <h2 style="display:inline;">{{service.name}}</h2>
        <button ion-fab mini color="danger"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab mini color="secondary"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But that's a very ad hoc solution. You really want to think, stylistically, about *why* you want it on the same line. Because using `h2` as an inline tag is akin to telling the HTML engine "I want a header, but I don't want it to be a header". Perhaps consider setting up some text in a `span` and using CSS to make it bigger, if you're just going for enlarged text.

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let service of services">
        <span style="font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;">{{service.name}}</span>
        <button ion-fab mini color="danger"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab mini color="secondary"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

That gives you basically the same visual effect, but now you're not fighting against HTML to get it.